# IE6 & 7, JavaScript "Member not found" bug

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I've written some JavaScript that embeds an image into a page.

The end result is successful on all browsers (even IE6 & 7) but with IE6 & 7 I get the message "Line 15, Character 5, Member not found". Here is the code:

```
09: var url = getUrl();
10: url += 'Impression';
11: url += '?' + getParams();

12: var img = new Image();
13: img.src = url;
14: img.style = "display = 'none';";
15: document.body.insertBefore(img, document.body.firstChild);
```

Are either `document.body.insertBefore` or `document.body.firstChild` not fully supported in IE6 or 7?

Comment: Why just not to use `document.body.appendChild(img)`?

Comment: Uhm, so if the result is succesful, how are you getting the error? I mean, it must be doing something it shouldn't be doing as a result of the error.

Comment: Yes, the image I was attaching was a 1x1 transparent gif and I was trying to set it as hidden as an extra precaution, however the setting it to hidden was failing but as it was already transparent I couldn't notice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE throws errors for invalid CSS property assignment. In this case, `img.style = "display = 'none';";` is invalid.

It should be either of these:

- `img.style.display = 'none';`
- `img.style.cssText = "display:none;";`